# can't delete foreign and primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

can't delete the primary and foreign key, it's simple table but i don't why this error

```
create table student (
    s_ID int ,
    S_NAMe varchar2 (10),
    S_major varchar2(20),
    D_ID number (10) ,
    Constraint PK_s_ID primary key (s_ID), 
    constraint FK_D_ID foreign key (D_ID) references dep (D_ID) );

    ALTER TABLE student DROP CONSTRAINT PK_s_ID cascade;
    alter table student drop constraint FK_D_ID;

    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
```

Comment: Please make sure constraint exists. SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'student';

Comment: it's the first time i use this command, once i run it i got these results
owner - constraint_name - table_name - column_name - position

what's that mean!

Comment: That means constraint did not get created. or you already deleted once and trying to delete again

Comment: so if the constraint exist i'll find it's name on results! will try it now

Comment: Before doing the DROP, show us the existance of that same constraint.

Comment: @tvCa i get the solution thank buddy ,, i wrote the constraints on lowercase and oracle accept the constraints and select statements only on uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SQL commands looks correct. You can use following command to make sure constraint exists.

```
SELECT * FROM user_cons_columns WHERE table_name = 'STUDENT'
```

If it returns no result, that means you either did not create a constraint or already dropped. You may be trying to re-run the same alter command more than once.

Comment: tried to create new tables with constraints but still no constraints on 
 SELECT constraint_name FROM user_cons_columns WHERE table_name = 'student'
don't know why i have this problem and how to fix it

Comment: @osama, ronin pointed a typo in the SQL, you need to use upper case always while selecting on this table, I updated answer accordingly

Comment: got it ,, appreciate your help guys